Dynamically access local data elsewhere on the server with sveltekit
On the server that my website runs off of, I have a JSON file located in /srv that updates every day with new data that I would like sveltekit to read every time the page is loaded.
//import latestVid from '/srv/site-scraper/latest-posts/latest-vid.json'

export async function load({ }) {
    let latestVid = await import('/srv/site-scraper/latest-posts/latest-vid.json').then(res => res.default)

    return {
        "latestArt" : latestArt
    }
  }

I have this script in my +page.server.js but doing it via import seems to cache the result on build (you can see I tried it two ways, same result), kuz changing the file or straight up deleting it changes nothing on the page where the data is used. It seems like the only way to dynamically access the file is via a fetch request with the actual https url of the file, but like I just feel like I should be able to dynamically access my server's filesystem if it's a serverside script, right??

Wait I found it, it seems so obvious now, just use readFileSync from fs.
import { readFileSync } from "node:fs"

export async function load({ }) {
    let latestVid

    try {
        latestVid = JSON.parse(readFileSync('/srv/site-scraper/latest-posts/latest-vid.json'))
    } catch (e) {
        return { "error" : e.default }
    }

    return {
        "latestVid" : latestVid
    }
  }

I just wasn't asking the right questions to find the right answers on Google to begin with.
